# Java Relative Path Issue

Tags: java, relative-path

I am facing an issue while trying to resolve a file path using relative paths in Java. I am not sure where I am failing at. Could you please help me out? Thanks!

```
@Test
public void testObjectNotNull() throws Exception{
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(getClass().getResource("./JavaPractice/resources/tests/codeeval/fileReaderTest.txt").toString());
    assertNotNull(fileReader);
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at components.com.codeeval.FileReader.FileReaderTest.testObjectNotNull(FileReaderTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Directory Structure:

JavaPractice

--resources.tests.codeeval.fileReaderTest.txt (File that I am trying to access)

--tests.components.com.codeeval.FileReader.FileReaderTest.java (junit which is trying to access the above file)

Comment: check this answer for how to specify relative path, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860616/problem-with-relative-file-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources are not files. They are typically JAR file entries. You should use the resource API of Class or ClassLoader. That can return you an InputStream.

Comment: Hi EJP, Thanks for mentioning this! What are the best practices for placing files like .txt and .xmls etc? Should I directly add them to the same package as the java source files?

Comment: The way I solved this:
1. Unmarked resources folder on Intellij as Resources root
2. Changed code:

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("resources\\tests\\codeeval\\fileReaderTest.txt");

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because  this

`getClass().getResource("./JavaPractice/resources/tests/codeeval/fileReaderTest.txt")`

is null. You are reading from the classpath and not a relative path per-se SO 
Change your code to
`getClass().getResource("tests/codeeval/fileReaderTest.txt")` and ensure that the resources folder is on your classpath. Also read up on [loading from classpath](http://www.journaldev.com/712/java-property-file-example-with-write-read-load-from-classpath-and-property-xml-file)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
InputStream in = Your_Class.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/tests/codeeval/abc.txt");

 assertNotNull(in);
 Reader fr = new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-8");
```

Comment: 'fr' cannot possibly be null, but 'in' can.

Comment: The idea is to *fix your answer,* actually.