# Reading a macro file and writing a excel file inside java application using poi

Tags: java, excel

I want a solution for reading a macro enabled(.xlsm) file and write the contents on a excel file.

I have tried out things as following.

```
String fileName = "sample.xlsm";
String path = "../documents/macro_CleanUp.xlsm";
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File(path));
XSSFWorkbook wb_template = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb_template);
workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet(fileName);
//filling contents of sheet
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName);            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
workbook.write(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

This works when i run in my localhost. but it doesnt work when i deploy the application into the server.

Can anyone tell where i am going wrong.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @MichaelFreake The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: actually above path doesnt work in localhost also , when i give the path as "c:\\Excel\\macro_CleanUp.xlsm" , it works in localhost.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is related to the path being specified.  You are trying to use a relative path, but it isn't working.  Take at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860616/problem-with-relative-file-path